# JQuery Syntax Similarity and Difference

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     alert("Hello World");
});
```

And this:

```
(function($){
    alert("Hello World");
})(jQuery);
```

do the same thing?

The former is what I commonly use and the second I have seen used in several plugins. Are they the same, if not then what are their differences and which one to use when?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not the same.

The former is a document.ready event handler. It will run as soon as the `DOMContentLoaded` event fires. It can also be written like this:

```
$(function() {
  alert("Hello World");
});
```

The latter is an [Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE). This will be executed immediately (as the name implies). Therefore you need to manually ensure that the DOM is in a state ready to be interacted with before you execute this logic. You can generally do this by placing the script at the end of the `body` tag, or within it's own document.ready handler. The latter is a little redundant when working with jQuery, though.